Enzyme Concentration vs Reaction rate curve
I aware that the Michaelis-Menten plot (Substrate concentration vs Reaction rate) is a hyperbola. Would the shape of enzyme concentration vs reaction rate also be a hyperbola? I would assume substrate concentration and enzyme concentration would be similar variables. I am wondering what the curve is when there is a limited amount of substrate, as unlimited substrate would lead to a linear curve. Thanks in advance :)

Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works.  Have a think about the conditions for generating a M-M plot and what you are measuring.

A plot of (initial) reaction rate vs enzyme concentration should be linear at all substrate concentrations, regardless of enzyme mechanism.
Doubling the enzyme concentration should exactly double the (initial) rate, and halving the enzyme conc should exactly halve the (initial) rate.
This must be the case at both high and low 'fixed' substrate concentrations.  By 'fixed', I mean the concentration of substrate at which the experiment is done.
If, in determining a Km for an enzyme, the lowest substrate concentration used is 10µM and the highest is (say) 1mM, then a plot of vI (initially rate) versus eo (enzyme concentration) should be linear at both 10µM and at 1mM.
To spell it out, doubling the enzyme concentration at a substrate concentration of 10µM should double the rate, and halving the enzyme concentration should half the rate, and the same applies at 1mM.
In kinetic parlance, "the vi versus eo should be linear", and is a prerequisite for a meaningful (steady-state) kinetic analysis
There are exceptions, such as some preparations of phosphofructokinase, where doubling the enzyme concentration does not double the initial rate (perhaps because of enzyme oligemerization) and this makes kinetic analysis very difficult.
Let's think about the consequences of this not being true.  How does one determine a meaningful Vmax?  If you determine the kinetic parameters at one enzyme concentration and I at another, we will come up with different values for Vmax if the vi versus eo is not linear.
Furthermore, what happens if, during the course of determining the kinetic parameters, I need to double the enzyme concentration in order to produce a detectable rate (typically, this happens at low [S])?  The assumption is that I can divide this rate by 2 in order that all rates are quoted at the same enzyme concentration.
I said above the this applies for all enzyme mechanisms. This includes Michaelis-Menten.  Pick any Km, Vmax, and [S]o, assign an arbitrary value of 1 to eo, and calculate the rate.  Now double this arbitrary value: the calculated initial rate doubles.
Finally, the above applies to steady-state enzyme kinetics where eo << [S]o
A comprehensive analysis of the case where the enzyme concentration is high is given by M. F. Chaplin in The effect of enzyme concentration on the Michaelis-Menten equation published in the January 1981 issue of Trends in Biochemical Sciences, but which does not seems to be indexed in PubMed or the like, and a link to a scanned copy may be found here (which amazingly still works).
